# R shiny fix sidebarPanel width to a specific pixels value?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I fix the sidebarPanel width to a specific value in pixels, instead of taking up a proportion of the total width compared to mainPanel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
sidebarPanel(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 140px; }"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 190px; }"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 180px; }")
  ),

  ...

)
```

Comment: `max-width` works great for my case, where I know how much space I want to use up for the sidebarPanel. Thanks!

Comment: It also works well with min-width (I came here looking for min not max)

Comment: Note that this doesn't take care of the main panel, which stops expanding to fill the room left by the sidebar once the sidebar hits its limit.