# Setting a fixed width for sidebarPanel without affecting separate wellPanel in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm trying to set my sidebarPanel to a fixed width, however, using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855907/r-shiny-fix-sidebarpanel-width-to-a-specific-pixels-value) affects the width of a different wellpanel in my layout. Is there a way to define the widths for the two separately? I'd like the wellpanel to span 100% in width.

In addition, my "close" button isn't actually 5px from the right, but somehow something is causes my main panel to extend, causing a scrollbar to appear. Which margin/padding is incorrect or missing to avoid this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(style = "margin:0px; padding: 0px;",
                       sidebarLayout(
                         sidebarPanel(style = "padding:0px; min-height: 100vh; position:relative;", 
                                      tags$head(
                                                tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 200px; }"),
                                                tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 200px; }"),
                                                tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 200px; }"),
                                                tags$style(".well {background-color:#9a9696;}")
                                      ),
                                      fluidRow(style = "margin:15px",
                                               actionButton("getdat", "Load Data", width='150px')
                                      )
                         ),
                         mainPanel(style = "margin:0px; padding: 0px;",
                                   fluidRow(style = "padding: 0px;",
                                            wellPanel(style = "padding: 25px; margin:0px; background:#e1e1e1;",
                                                      actionButton("quit", "Close" ,width="150px",
                                                                   style = "position: absolute; 
                                                                   top: 15px; 
                                                                   right: 5px; 
                                                                   z-index:10000;")
                                            )),
                                   fluidRow(style = "padding: 0px; margin:0px;",
                                            plotlyOutput("plot"),
                                   ))
)))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    if (input$quit == 1){
      stopApp()
    }
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `width` argument of `sidebarPanel` and `mainPanel`:

```r
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    ......,
    width = 3
  ),
  mainPanel(
    ......,
    width = 9
  )
)
```

These two widths must sum to 12 to occupy all the available space. By default these widths are 4 and 8.

If you really want to use some CSS, you can attribute an id to the sidebar:

```r
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    id = "sidebar",
    ......
  ),
```

then use it in the CSS:

```r
tags$style(type="text/css", "#sidebar { max-width: 200px; }")
```

but if you do that, the sidebar will still take 1/3 of the available width (`width = 4`), although the well panel will be smaller.

The scrollbars are due to your `padding: 0px`, I think.

---

## Edit

Sorry for my "easiest way" proposal, I misunderstood the problem. Here is a UI fulfilling what you desire, I think. I don't use the `sidebarLayout`. I also removed a `fluidRow` because a `fluidRow` has the CSS property `margin: -15px`, which yielded an undesirable result. The horizontal scrollbar has gone away.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 200px; }"),
      tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 200px; }"),
      tags$style(".well {background-color:#9a9696;}")
    ),
    style = "margin:0px; padding: 0px;",
    tags$div(
      style = "display: flex;",
      wellPanel( # this is the sidebar
        style = "padding:0px; min-height: 100vh; max-width: 200px;", 
        fluidRow(
          style = "margin:15px",
          actionButton("getdat", "Load Data", width='150px')
        )
      ),
      tags$div( # this is the main panel
        style = "margin:0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%",
        tags$div(
          style = "padding: 0px;",
          wellPanel(
            style = "padding: 25px; margin:0px; background: #e1e1e1;",
            actionButton(
              "quit", "Close", width="150px",
              style = "position: absolute; top: 15px; right: 5px; z-index:10000;"
            )
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          style = "padding: 0px; margin:0px;"#,
          #plotlyOutput("plot"),
        ))
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    if (input$quit == 1){
      stopApp()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```